# Apparmor service doesn't start

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, apparmor

I tried reinstalling it and installing apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu but nothing resolves the problem. Always get this error:

```
apparmor.service - LSB: AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apparmor; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since vie 2018-02-16 14:16:17 CET; 4min 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 680 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

feb 16 14:16:12 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
feb 16 14:16:17 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 apparmor[680]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
feb 16 14:16:17 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 apparmor[680]:  * AppArmor not available as kernel LSM.
feb 16 14:16:17 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 apparmor[680]:    ...fail!
feb 16 14:16:17 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
feb 16 14:16:17 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
feb 16 14:16:17 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Unit entered failed state.
feb 16 14:16:17 migue-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a` and `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture} \t${Version}\n' linux-image\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p'`? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a custom kernel ? Running in any sort of virtual machine ?

Comment: I'm running kernel 4.14.19.

Comment: uname -a
Lenovo-G50-70 4.14.19-041419-generic #201802131030 SMP Tue Feb 13 10:31:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: sudo dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture} \t${Version}\n' linux-image\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p'
linux-image-4.13.0-35-generic:amd64  4.13.0-35.39~16.04.1
linux-image-4.14.19-041419-generic:amd64  4.14.19-041419.201802131030
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-35-generic:amd64  4.13.0-35.39~16.04.1
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64  4.13.0.35.54